# "Premeditated" kill bonus in Sniper Elite 3 - what is it?

Tags: sniper-elite-3

There is a variety of tags popping up and giving you bonus XP when you take a nazi out. The one I don't understand is 'premeditated'. What does it mean? How to get it? I know it is not given for tagging enemies before a kill, this one is called 'tagged kill'.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer but all I've found is `Should you eventually kill the marked foes, one of the score bonuses is "Premeditated" meaning you had them marked before taking them down. ` But as you said that seems to be the 'tagged kill' one.

Answer (score 4):

i have been wondering this myself, and looking over the videos recorded (somewhat randomly) on my xbone, it says "premeditated" on the middle of the screen and "tagged kill" in the list appearing on the right after a kill.

this seem to be 100% consistent in the videos i have recorded (but it's only like 6 videos, so it's not like hard evidence). neither ghost-bonus nor guard alert level seem to be an issue.

edit:
i also have a video of a long shot of a tagged target not giving "premeditated" but i think that's simply because there are only room for 4 bonuses on the middle of the screen. in this case it was:

```
 middle screen:
    headshot
    eagle-eyed
    isolated
    ghost

 right side:
    ghost kill bonus
    rifle kill
    empty lung
    long distance bonus
    tagged kill
    headshot bonus
```

i assume "eagle-eyed" is the same as "long distance bonus" the same way that "premeditated" is the same as "tagged kill".

Answer (score 3):

to get the 'premeditated' tag, you have to mark the soldiers, then plan their execution, using a landmine, or firing against something that can blow them up.

For example I got that by blowing an antiaerial machine gun by shooting a gas tank.

Answer (score 0):

Premeditated kill bonus is for when the enemy is looking for you and you are watching and have either laid a trap such as trip mines or whatnot, or you have been watching them for a while and have killed them... Basically any FATAL attack on an enemy that has been planned in advance :D Hope this helps!!